# TypeError string indices must be integers when execute query within function in pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm having a trouble when trying to use function to query data in MSSQL using pyodbc, the function is:

```
def getUserList(connection):
    li = []
    cur = connection.cursor()
    query = 'select username, password, firstname, lastname, description, phone,'+
            'email, isAdmin, isAutoBoot from users_tbl'    
    cur.execute(query)
    for usr, pwd, fn, ln, des, ph, em, ad, au in cur.fetchall():        
        temp = User(usr, pwd, fn, ln, des, ph, em, ad, au)            
    cur.close()
    #con.close()
    return li
```

When I import the module and run this function, it encounter the TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#71>", line 1, in <module>
  import_user.getUserList(s_con)
File "c:/python27/mymodule\import_user.py", line 12, in getUserList
  cur.execute(query)
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However if i copy and run each of these line in Python IDLE, it runs fine and no error when execute the cursor. It happens both when I pass pyodbc or sqlite connection as input parameter.

Thanks

Comment: I get SyntaxError on the line that ends with `+`.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve syntax problem, change these lines:

```
query = 'select username, password, firstname, lastname, description, phone,'+
        'email, isAdmin, isAutoBoot from users_tbl'
```

to either (newline not preserved):

```
query = ('select username, password, firstname, lastname, description, phone, '
         'email, isAdmin, isAutoBoot from users_tbl')
```

or (newline preserved):

```
query = """select username, password, firstname, lastname, description, phone, 
           email, isAdmin, isAutoBoot from users_tbl"""
```

See the [Maximum Line Length section](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) of the style guide for more info on line wrapping.

Comment: thanks beargle but it does not resolve the problem, I even tried to put the whole query string in one line.

Anyway, I restarted IDLE and run it again and the function works fine, must be something that's interfere with the module import. Apparently the function works fine if I run the module from command line